# MonoDevelop, Teamaddins, and Mono.Posix 4.0 on Windows 7

Tags: tfs, monodevelop

I'm running MonoDevelop 2.8.6.5 and TeamAddins (TFS support for MD). Its version also appears to be 2.8.6.5.

When attempting to access the TeamAddins Options pane (Tools > Options > Version Control > TeamAddins), I get the following error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Posix, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at TeamAddins.VersionControl.TFS.Gui.TFSOptionsPanelWidget.Build()
   at TeamAddins.VersionControl.TFS.Gui.TFSOptionsPanelWidget..ctor()
   at TeamAddins.VersionControl.MonoDevelop.TFSOptionsPanel.CreatePanelWidget()
   at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Dialogs.OptionsDialog.CreatePageWidget(SectionPage page)
   at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Dialogs.OptionsDialog.ShowPage(OptionsDialogSection section)
   at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Dialogs.OptionsDialog.OnSelectionChanged(Object s, EventArgs a)
```

I've seen SO posts describing the same problem for Android development within MonoDevelop, but so far haven't found a solution that fixes this problem for TeamAddins.

Comment: I am also getting the same error when accessing the TeamAddins Options pane after updating MonoDevelop to 2.8.6.5 from 2.8.  Apparently there is an update coming for TeamAddins, but I can not find it:  

from teamaddins.com:  "Oups Xamarin make somes change in version control with monodevelop 2.8.0.2 .... and teamAddins stop fonctionning. I update the Addins v2.8.6.2 to solve trouble. Go to repository."

Comment: This error is still occurring in MonoDevelop 3.0 and the latest version of TeamAddins.